# Viewpager horizontal scrollbar not showing up - Android-

Tags: android

In my viewpager Ive enabled horizontal scrollbar by such featuredPager.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);

However it never shows up or does anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled is a method of `View`. It will not work as an indicator for the pages of a ViewPager. You can make your own View that does this, by listening using an implementation of `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`. However, there are already some libraries that can handle this for you, like [this one](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator). I would recommend you to try that first.